# Trim blank line with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, highlightjs

I am styling syntax with `HighlightJS` but I had a problem with space and line-number mismatch.

**Problem :** If the `syntax` is not started immediately after `<code>` it appends a blank line.

It is not possible always to insert syntax this way, I am looking for JavaScript solution, to remove the first blank line only.

This is simple JavaScript **HowTo** if anyone can mention the solution of this issue - -

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dsmith33/qkz8L0m1/)**

I am looking for a `JavaScript` solution or `HighlightJS` plugin if any

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Testing HighlightJS</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.6.0/styles/routeros.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Testing HighlightJS</h3>
    <h4>CSS</h4>
    <pre><code class="language-css">
    .class{
    font-size: 0.85rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: monospace;
    }
    h1 .header{
    font-size: 1.5rem;;
    font-family: Arial;
    }
    </code></pre>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.6.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.6.0/languages/css.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlightjs-line-numbers.js/2.6.0/highlightjs-line-numbers.min.js"></script>
    <script>hljs.highlightAll(); hljs.initLineNumbersOnLoad();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[blank-space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omzOH.png)

Comment: Currently unable to provide proper answer so I will comment

```var y = document.querySelectorAll("language-css");
for(var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
  y[i].innerHTML = y[i].innerHTML.replace("\n", "");
}```


From https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-help/issues/191

Comment: Here is a fiddle with the implemented solution. https://jsfiddle.net/mbkgqr21/

Please note that this solution will remove newline from all code blocks on the page. Not just the one you want. So if you will create multiple code blocks in the future and you want new line on those. This will delete from there as well

Comment: @pevecg could you look into this - https://jsfiddle.net/dsmith33/h6ywgfa8/17/ I am trying to add - copy button, and clipboard, action. Also the `copy` button is not aligning, add `style: hover` visible, otherwise, faint - grey text only,