# can not add copy copy event with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add copy button to Highlight-JS block. I am getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of undefined.

The code maybe broken, - How to add the clipboard event to all the code(blocks), I can not figure out after some of the event errors.

I am trying to build copy button with this [guide](https://raulterhes.com/posts/copy-code-snippets-to-clipboard-with-javascript/) and my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66703942/trim-blank-line-with-javascript)

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dsmith33/h6ywgfa8/17/)**

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var y = document.querySelectorAll("pre code");
for(var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
  y[i].innerHTML = y[i].innerHTML.replace("\n", "");
  
  //copy-span
let codeSyn = y[i].querySelector("tbody");
var textspan = document.createElement("SPAN");
textspan.innerText = "Copy";
codeSyn[i].querySelector('tr').appendChild(textspan);

//copy-clipboard - 
const copyTextHandler = () => {
const text = codeBlock.innerText;

navigator.clipboard.writeText(text).then(
      () => {
        copySuccess.classList.add('show-message');
        setTimeout(() => {
          copySuccess.classList.remove('show-message');
        }, 2500);
      },
      () => {
        console.log('Error writing to the clipboard');
      }
    );
  };

  copyButton.addEventListener('click', copyTextHandler);
  
}
})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Testing HighlightJS</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.6.0/styles/routeros.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Testing HighlightJS</h3>
    <h4>CSS</h4>
    <pre><code class="language-css">
    .class{
    font-size: 0.85rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: monospace;
    }
    
    h1 .header{
    font-size: 1.5rem;;
    font-family: Arial;
    }
    </code></pre>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.6.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.6.0/languages/css.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlightjs-line-numbers.js/2.6.0/highlightjs-line-numbers.min.js"></script>
    <script>hljs.highlightAll(); hljs.initLineNumbersOnLoad();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @mplungjan I am trying to build, this is just mockup from https://raulterhes.com/posts/copy-code-snippets-to-clipboard-with-javascript/

Comment: `.querySelector()` returns one element (or `null`). What do you expect `codeSyn[i]` (with `let codeSyn = y[i].querySelector("tbody");`) to do?

Comment: I mentioned the problem. `codeSyn` will always be one element (or `null`) only, hence `[i]` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Andreas codeSyn - I am trying to add span to multiple https://snipboard.io/AFE1Wx.jpg such code blocks, please understand the use case, and change as you want - copy button, and copy event is required

Comment: please change - as much required, this is just mockup(sorry for being broken code) - for querySelector - means - span will be after the `ith` `tbody` - I could be wrong,

Answer (score 1):

So here are all errors gone expect the write to clipboard message due to permission issues

Working and copying version:

https://plungjan.name/SO/clipboard/

This version will give permission errors from the StackSnippet sandboxed environment

I am waiting for a callback function from the highlighter, for now I use a timeout.

```js
let copySuccess;
//copy-clipboard - 
const copyTextHandler = (e) => {
  const codeBlock = document.querySelectorAll(".hljs-ln")[e.target.dataset.idx];
  const text = codeBlock
    .innerText
    .trim()
    .replace(/\s+/g, " ")
    .replace(/}/g, "}\n")
    .replace(/{ /g, "{\n  ")
    .replace(/;/g, ";\n  ")
  copySuccess.classList.remove('hide');
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(text).then(() => setTimeout(() => copySuccess.classList.add('hide'), 2000),
    (e) => {
      console.log('Error writing to the clipboard', e.message);
      copySuccess.classList.add('hide');
    }
  );
};


window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  copySuccess = document.getElementById("copySuccess");
  hljs.highlightAll();
  hljs.initLineNumbersOnLoad();
  setTimeout(function() {
    var y = document.querySelectorAll("table.hljs-ln");
    for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
      y[i].innerHTML = y[i].innerHTML.replace("\n", "");
      //copy-span
      let codeSyn = y[i].querySelector("tbody");
      if (codeSyn) {
        var textspan = document.createElement("SPAN");
        textspan.dataset.idx = i,
          textspan.innerHTML = "COPY";
        textspan.style.color = "red";
        textspan.style.border = "1px solid black";
        textspan.style.marginLeft = "10px";
        const header = codeSyn.closest("pre").previousElementSibling.appendChild(textspan);
        textspan.addEventListener('click', copyTextHandler);
      }
    }
  }, 1000)
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Testing HighlightJS</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.6.0/styles/routeros.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h3>Testing HighlightJS <span id="copySuccess" class="hide">Copying...</span></h3>
  <h4>CSS</h4>
  <pre><code class="language-css"> .class {
   font-size: 0.85rem;
   font-weight: 600;
   font-family: monospace;
 }
    
 h1 .header {
   font-size: 1.5rem;
   font-family: Arial;
 }
</code></pre>

  <h4>CSS</h4>
  <pre><code class="language-css"> .class {
   font-size: 0.85rem;
   font-weight: 600;
   font-family: monospace;
 }
    
 h2 .header {
   font-size: 1.5rem;
   font-family: Arial;
 }
</code></pre>

  <h4>CSS</h4>
  <pre><code class="language-css"> .class {
   font-size: 0.85rem;
   font-weight: 600;
   font-family: monospace;
 }
    
 h3 .header {
   font-size: 1.5rem;
   font-family: Arial;
 }
</code></pre>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.6.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.6.0/languages/css.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlightjs-line-numbers.js/2.6.0/highlightjs-line-numbers.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Updated and made a  [Working version](https://plungjan.name/SO/clipboard/) that copies

Comment: Just play with my replace statements

Comment: could you see this updated https://jsfiddle.net/dsmith33/5jzbs94c/5/ not working

Comment: Clone and don't use position absolute https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/68du0c2z/